# Facing issue with my canvas after update the kendo.all.min.js to 2014.3.1411

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In my application i have updated kendo.all.min.js to 2014.3.1411 after that my svg draw lines in canvas is not working and drag and drop to canvas not able to finding the target at canvas. What is the problem I am unable to find. But I need this upgrade of kendo.all.min.js for groupColumns (Nested Columns) in kendo grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer.... Applied a class="curpoint js-no-pan" on the resourced start point. It increased my zoom level and its working fine for me.